# Javascript Function is sorting after index rather than name of files

Tags: javascript, json, database, sorting, html-table

I have this database and that sorting function. The sorting is done to a html table which took the data from database.json file. The problem is that when it sorts, it sorts them from their index, rather than the location name, as asked. For example in this case it will only reverse the first set of data with the last one. (1,2,3) -> (3,2,1)

Please help...

**THE DATABASE**

```
[
    {
        "title": "Great big event",
        "location": "Grand plaza"
    },
    {
        "title": "Cross cultural food tasting",
        "location": "Melius Restaurant",
        "date": "18 December 2018",
        "time": "8 PM",
        "description" : "Food tasting event where you can enjoy a mix of 10 famous cuisines"
    },
    {
        "title": "Small dining event",
        "location": "Cafe Il diroma",
        "date": "10 February 2019",
        "time": "6 AM",
        "description": "The perfect place for casual dinners"
    }
]
```

**SORTING FUNCTION**

```
location.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a.location < b.location) { return -1; }
    if(a.location > b.location) { return 1; }
    return 0;
})
</script>
<body>
    <div class="show-inline-block">
        <button onclick="location.sort(a,b)" class="button button2">Sort table</button>
    </div>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
```

UPDATE:
The Sorting is done to a HTML table made WITH the data from database.json

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped" id="myTable" >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        % for k in displaykeys:
        <th scope="col" style="padding-left:30px">{{k.title()}}</th>
        % end   # Usual python indention to structure code does not work in .tpl files - "end" is used instead to end a block
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      % for i, d in enumerate(displaydata):    # displaydata is expected to be a list of dictionaries
      % link_url = "/events/" + str(i + 1)     # relative url to detailed view
      <tr>
        % for k in displaykeys:     # Go thru the keys in the same order as for the headline row
        <td style="padding-left:30px"><a href="{{link_url}}" alt="See details">{{displaydata[i][k]}}</a></td>
        % end   # Usual python indention to structure code does not work in .tpl files - "end" is used instead to end a block
      </tr>
      % end
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I also tried using this sort : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sort_table_desc
Still the same issue. It somehow sorts after their order in the database instead of the name of element.

Answer (score 0):

Your sort code is not the problem. The problem is the structure of your overall code.

`location` is a Global and not a name you should redefine. Also, in your HTML `onclick` you are passing `a`, and `b` which have no values and are undefined.

You need to set up a callback function for your button's `click` event and in that function, you can perform the sort.

See inline comments below:

```js
// Don't use global names as identifiers. "location" is a global.
let loc = [
    {
        "title": "Great big event",
        "location": "Grand plaza"
    },
    {
        "title": "Cross cultural food tasting",
        "location": "Melius Restaurant",
        "date": "18 December 2018",
        "time": "8 PM",
        "description" : "Food tasting event where you can enjoy a mix of 10 famous cuisines"
    },
    {
        "title": "Small dining event",
        "location": "Cafe Il diroma",
        "date": "10 February 2019",
        "time": "6 AM",
        "description": "The perfect place for casual dinners"
    }
];

// Get your DOM references
let btn = document.querySelector("button");

// Set up event handling in JavaScript, not HTML
btn.addEventListener("click", sort);

// Set up a function that can be called when the button is clicked
function sort(){
  // Do your sort in that function
  loc.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a.location < b.location) { return -1; }
    if(a.location > b.location) { return 1; }
    return 0;
  });
  
  // Show results
  console.log(loc);
}
```

```html
<div class="show-inline-block">
  <button class="button button2">Sort table</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Could you please take a look at the code again? I updated it with the HTML table part.

Comment: @manubmxnsb You wouldn't sort the HTML. You'd sort the data (as my answer shows how to do) and then re-build the HTML to match that.

Comment: Yeah but using that solution, every time that i put something new in the datastore I will have to update the 'let loc' which is not what is expected of me.. Could you please help me change something in my solution so it does the sorting corectly?
The sorting works it just doesn't compare the right things.

Comment: How else would you get something new in the data store? `loc` is going to have to be updated, but you don't have to do it manually, you'd take the input from the UI and update `loc` with that input.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow correctly, are you saying that loc is updating itself with any new daa that is input by the user?

Comment: Yes. when the user inputs data, that data is appended to `loc` and when the sort button is pressed, loc gets sorted and then table is then re-rendered to show the newly sorted array data. This is called separation of concerns. Just worry about maintaining the integrity of the data and the table is nothing more than a reflection of the data.

Comment: The thing is that I've been given this code that gets the elements and puts them in the HTML table before giving me the chance to change to sort them. I cannot change the order, its for a school project. So given this case, would that method still be relevant? -- Edit : I might have some blind spots since I'm new to javascript atm...
Also ,all the results have to be modified & shown in the table

Comment: Well, you haven't shown the code that accepts elements and puts them in the table, so it's hard to say. Unfortunately, many teachers don't understand best-practices and methodologies and may not realize that they are teaching poor techniques.

Comment: It's there I updated the post. Unfortunatelly, you're completely righ about the teachers! After 3 hours of search on the internet and this talk I really see how innefective is their code. However, to make this effective would mean to rewrite all their code, which is not what they want out of me ,sadly :/

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that allows a user to input new data.

Comment: What I do have however is another option of code. It is longer, though it works on the HTML table but It sorts them wrong. Could you please check this link? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53821948/how-to-sort-html-name-table-with-javascript
I've posted this question 2-3 hours before

Comment: That part is in another file called 'typein.py' . The whole package is a simple yet not effective site (half-done by the teachers) using Bottle Two in Python with Javascript and HTML.

Comment: In that solution, I think the problem is here:
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];

      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];